# How can i pass an array of multiple types to a method and prevent the co-variance of the array from allowing incompatible subtypes?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Background**

I need to be able to check the compatibility of a type against certain criteria when adding it to group. I have this working when adding single instances, but would also like to implement the ability to add multiple instances of different types at the same time.

**Problem**

When adding multiple types as an array the compatibility check works - as it removes incompatible types from the array union type - but if any of the eliminated types are subtypes of allowed types within the array the covariant nature of the array means there's no error.

**Example**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICWBnAwgewLbQIbkQEYA2sAPAELywAe4sAdgCbLwDK4ATovQOYDyHAHIBXTAVgcAkvXZdeAkWIl9h4AHzwAvPFDw98SjTpMWs7vyGjxUmZ3MKry1fAD8bO-MtKbZz4usq4FS0DMwGruEAXPD0sABuEvDRsQkcANygEDAIKBjYeIQkALLCRPjQJBTBxmG%20Fv4S0nUO3oEA2gC6Gpq6%20khoWLj4xGTkbfSOHF0ZYLOgAMZEOMgsRZAA4hzowtDwAN6ZIH3QXHF4CAD68%20hEJPP46PTRzV7WTR71k%200dWvCdM709DhGIwqkZQqYPi03rY5J9Wqo1AAKHAcHjRXKDAojChqACUkTi6EQjH2gL68HAAAsUAA6K43O4Pei06DCZBUlFovEzPoAX0OfWBjBKZUQFVG1Qh7jh0MasPsryc4E6yNRPGQGIG%20WGxVK5Uq5DUnXgADIDAT4ESSWTZhT9OrkLSAGboDgAURw805XPRMsVDR8UKVHECeK0GgOR3tFOpdIZt1g90Qj1Z7M56p55P5WejegFIALhwA9KWy%20WK5Wq9Wa7W6-WGzXDgslit-bxpIHArbyTQk6pYEjuGzwNFkB9LRNvLaY-AOLBwMIOPR4ABGXn6AtFkCLZaQuHvWUh7tR3vUft0If0Edjie3uHwAA%20MUmM5j88Xy7XG-zoG3u7bF5A0PAMvmcU882CC9B2HVR73MJ8X28S1xwfZ8p2sN97Q-JcV3Xckt2bHdHnHeAeC2HZfliAB3eA1k2bZoCRXNQHIxjaWFJEaPbHhOzA8BmNzNidg4kEuNgWi6hAvx%20MEmZhOgUTGHEyTg2AhUZIRAS8RYkAFKU0UDUHcYJJ46T4QCVRmIAGhiUygMmcy5VDKy8Q6ISKMU4VDPFEgkRM1SD3oLtXPc%20TPIM-VfOM7ipOC2S8Vs2KPic49Qp5eBSzM%20KtPgDltiIUl5hwdkEBwFcJC2DhWIi7yoolfzkqCkLtKS%20yUo0izlRsuzAtA7xUpa5iwsy4tspavKqQKoqSuQMqKo4KqiKy91qDge5YEYYtGFgZBEHnUlxCpHA4hTJcSwAKh0PM4xYajpvgYrSvgHBHsGRASCoRa3UBQFJB2nBbkgeBHiIYGmvMPitOY%20B7tKQ6EGEJgJCIbhNqQFcDspdAMcYRBiroSljqCRBwAAchYakEHQZ1nVCBCoDgQU9D4AAlZmkGdImyoIdAEn6GJ0CCaB0BWQpYFsqmqHofB5xexacGBuHCvgcR4CRnaOFR2JSW4OdNtsghnCl65sA%20hBKrdeBMF25AcB4BBld1%20hFmEHbuZB2n6d4Slsg52BaR4cb%20IF%20ghbenVxdh0mqQ9hTQAu4savYuqxQagLg%20hxLeuyhys7avrNJhPPLO0sLDiAA)

This is a contrived/simplified example to demonstrate the issue.

The group logic:

```
type isCompatible<B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut> = 
    B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut ? StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut extends B ? B : never : never;

type isCompatibleMultiple<B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut[]> =
     isCompatible<B[number]>



class MyGroup {

    private _collection: StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut[] = [];

    add<B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut>(arg: isCompatible<B>):void {
        this._collection.push(arg);
    }

    addMultiple<B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut[]>(args: isCompatibleMultiple<B>[] & B): void {

        args.forEach((arg: StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut) => {
            this._collection.push(arg);
        });
    }
}
```

```
class StringInNumberOut {

    execute(input: string): number {
        return 1;
    }
}

class StringInStringOrNumberOut {

    execute(input: string): string | number {
        return 1;
    }
}

class StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut {

    execute(input: string | number): string | number {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Adding instances to the group:

```
const group = new MyGroup();

group.add(new StringInNumberOut()); // ERROR
group.add(new StringInStringOrNumberOut());
group.add(new StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut());

group.addMultiple([new StringInStringOrNumberOut(), new StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut()]);
group.addMultiple([new StringInNumberOut()]); // ERROR
group.addMultiple([new StringInNumberOut(), new StringInStringOrNumberOut()]); // StringInNumberOut should cause an error but doesn't
```

**I understand why this is occurring** - The inferred type for the type parameter B becomes:

`(StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut)[]`

But as `StringInNumberOut` is a subtype of `StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut`, and arrays are covariant, it's also now a valid type in the array, so no error is shown.

**Solution so far**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFQK5QDYwQewKoDsCWmuAPAnDAB5gy4AmAznAIa4QDaAugHxwC8ibXEgC2AIxgAnDgG5QoSLDj56AYUzCoTMPlHpiAIXJUaDOAGUwE-LgDmAeQkA5EeIkBJXBau2HzsZLskMB5+UDhwuENKajpGL2t7JxdJD3ifJP8JQLA4AH5zSwTfZPdPQvS-V2yjGNNDfMMALjhcGAA3SThm1o6JWRB5aHhlNQ0tHXQAWSRUbTQYAxqTOPLEypSy7zWS7M4QsIi4AAYl2LgACgB9EfVNbV0Yadn8eY9WiVIUdCw8QhJ9LhcACUeRa7U6zX0-UGimuqlu4weTzm6DekmI2FOpjS20yqVWxUy2X2IEOmOiywKW0Jrnx1IyVSCoLYNzG9z02C4HCxjEE4KkoJOzUx3X50IGEoAxqgmPRGJMIABxCSYFBwADeclJESgVjaWngl0lmFQ6El2iIzRxNI21oZASCnD4cE44sOTFotEWFLOdvWpT9OyCXHOTAkNmarLuEwWAKBjTamHwtA1B0O4TAAAtlAA6I0ms0W3A5qBIeiZ0PhoH9Q4AXy17s9yJeeiixl9BPtAc7-t23ErNnokfhbJjzfmBh4ADJIvG4Ink6mJemImHBzmAGaYCQAUSYkorA6tPZKdKKXeyIN4PE12pXhyzufzppg5r+JbLFbX1bT6drP7vOB6xAYCtQAeggyCoOgmDYLg+CEMQpDkPgrVQGlWUVi2DxeyZW9f0oV8ghgc5rFLMBmnoVY5yETIl3vOAJBgMAkAkXA4AARhrCJgNAkAMLlKkEjPCogxyfDAMIyViNI3ByMo6iFK2OAAB8WhKej7yYli2M47jwl4rUBKw89-RE3FGXEhsIikmSyKCJSElU9TMjnKjlLU2jXE0ldtNY9iuN-QyJSMogqLgGwVTVfhWgAdzgBVlVVKBzgA0BIuSnMPVoc44qE2wcLE1KAIylAss9XKYHinFzJtLIgmK-pSqgcqcrywM8U2UyiqBNKQGa1rx3Qc4+Wq1ZaovBqgQAGjBMb6TMrrRKJKaOCBdKopa7KhpI0b8psQqVrAVK1qazbBpmFFdva8bcFw46Zrm-a6om+6TpK87tsultrqq-bDss1LZpuhbTyWiyHQe4G-pq8G6uyd7xXAsC4B3ChYHNGBaDA2gYHofAmJTcRMyYNpCFY8CACo4DTNxcaYU0IDgIhUCZkHhLunq4Fi1VUCJ+AkDoSRUGsLGlHYwm4DATBxdofBJQNKWSZyfAwAAckYLN4EwDcNxMJyFBgay4DsAAlY38A3JX4CYURMA6JRGFwTAcigTA5RjWatfIXBtCY5gJAkJgmZ5mZ+bgQXcYkEXWhTaxGLF0NGHEVBMFix7RCZb3jQ0fB0HIQPtzgYQ8foJgbHgUO+fF6UkFx63md1-XbCloZjZgHMbH+zmjsdloXbgHPowebnVczBvmtASmwI2zKvueeYRvZgqe8Bx7l4OuHJqhp6OtpLe3qBU6gA)

The only solution i've been able to come up with so far is an all or nothing approach.

```
type TupleToUnion<T extends any[]> = T[number];

type isCompatible<B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut> = 
    B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut ? StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut extends B ? B : never : never;

type isCompatibleMultiple<B extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut[]> =
     0 extends (_isCompatibleMultipleInner<TupleToUnion<B>>) ? never : B;

type _isCompatibleMultipleInner<U extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut> =
    U extends StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut ? [isCompatible<U>] extends [never] ? 0 : U : never;
```

So if any of the types are incompatible `never` is returned, otherwise the original array type is returned.

But this is not very user friendly, as it gives no indication of which types within the array are incompatible.

**Question**

Is there a better solution to this that would give a more concise error?

[Updated example showing edge cases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/LAKA9GAECSDOkBcAWBTSBjJBDAdgczQQHsZYBhIgWwAcsEBLAIwBs0ATAV0JOXviQQJqsAFwQ89ZB0YA6dFTCV66AE5FYRAGYIwAFQCe1FAGVV9ajr6wusMACYAjAHY7ATkgB+SKFAJDaOAoaOiZWAB4AIQA+SABeUEhEyA4cAGscIgB3HEgUAA8EFBw2eAAKCNyCopLIYwA5YnrPBKTW+sa6ysLi+AqPFtbEnBQANxQVSBFktIzsyen0rJwASk9IYbGJqYifEHRmLFh4AFl9AHE1DmpIAG9d1uoVehG6NAB9eWZWdAYiHCn2kR6gBtAC6cUgYIA3Pcklg2GxIl1qvBAfUoqUsCo8FNAlRaAwWChIlFllMRkR6GxbgNBrxYDIPkQvigfvQ-jJqBxYEhMdjljCQK0AL6wxLwtjHDjMBjUcIVfLdGpoupgjG01pYvCiSEyPU3SEAaUg9ByqRQ+i0kAioNx5HxISJkWBhtBMWFoNpZMgFKpNJAGrh2IZmiIKgAolhMKU+Tjag0gXVVrEYnchYMM-TGZ9vr8cJzubytQLA4lhSX02XQKKA7WIPWG42m82W622+2O5227t9odUcROmnaflWRxCqVTVyEFNYAgnvhvTgOJRGON-RnEioUAgOCocg5BSLqz2Dkdah1-cO8qPx5OxzO56a8N7Z-O8JAAD7rZeriZpjeQFuO57pAB60jWNagL2Z4qpelaVDeKATjgU4Pm+n7fiu4wvo++AYUuWF-qWgHbru+6HkkEG7D2fyzpAeCXNcsTrCgmSQKcFxEFcpQVqADFcdQMgSqUwxscYA48RW-FXEJCIiax56JpJgrSYJwmifGHTKbsqmyZK0qyqwpTAhp4lKcsAA0LFiQm9Q8aCyx8YxelSjK5hGSZClmXU9lSc5EquYZSGeWJEmWdZmnmQ5Kn+QigXucFplhVZpm2T54VJVFvF1lA4YACJnOGkBkAAgsY4ZWXlADy4bGDAujsSVui6OGABKHgAIRQbRCCQFgEIhYp6UpV5aX2TFAkuQZCWYgKkAQLkKhqCouxYDIoYRlGvKxsmqa0rpwnFoK5aCqAa0bZG0axgCaUYd5u3rkkB1yUd1bZedYaXdtWo3R0D3-k9sVsDtx3ZaAC3hmVACa7HQMYuglYaRW6FVjVI91OB0Ywv2JmCA2ZcNEUquNTmTQF01ykhjDZbIF1bTGP2RfU-37UDINvadtbg1AAACzCmqkkACEIogQJk4syH4RiwGYFgHPgMhhngYBsEQ6C2NgxSMEQRCpGAW6sIcKAALQZIUthSygMtPBYxsAMzGw4MgCJQzAAMSUFg1BGGwxuW7Axt-H7VysAHuC+1iKhYPosC7GAABUCT0AA5JQJo4IUW6zig1KmtMbDjLO4dPogqCQGw9CaJo4xFOgaCrggmQoEU7Fe7oRAAApqEosBoOHrfUO3XdUHwKB2DICTQDk9KVFgNCsKXaBcUIY4mvAVJFAw6BYMwkCMKvyB0Mn8Bm4vGBG5AG19XFFOsKA8dgLslsD0P3ej2EDWKiiCyzDgaoQgaF06dIDmktJoSAuhbSQGHj3YkugXRukgMKQUz8KBhgrjgV4+MfzjBSjglQoIUH+GgW-XuaCVAYKwcxY4bdO6kOJOQyhhQohQnmlAYEMD34EV-FEKynDe5hG4eMKInpazPxoYPOhI9e52A-siHoP8lj-2YsCPUMhAHGjzqAq0kCpj8LgQg90hDfDEP0Yw00rw7AQgka-aRY8wjmMwcw1hC0OH0MEfg3hJC7EeMIiIoAA)

Comment: This question looks interesting. Could you please provide minimum reproducible example? I mean you have provided an example, but I'm wondering if it is possible to reduce it a bit. Also please comment in ts playground expected and unexpected errors. It will be much easier to understand this problem

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks, i've simplified the example code and tried to add expected results to the ts playground. Please let me know if it's still not clear what's expected

Comment: Just want to clarify. All errors in ts playground are expected and you only are interested in more elegant solution ?

Comment: Yes, the existing errors are expected and i've added comments next to the lines of code where errors should be shown but aren't

Comment: I don't see any comments :( in ts playground

Comment: sorry, they should now also be added to the second playground link

Comment: Oof, names like `StringOrNumberInStringOrNumberOut` are giving me blurred vision; in what follows I'm going to use names like `StoN` (read "string to number"), `StoSN` ("string to string-or-number), and `SNtoSN` ("string-or-number to string-or-number") instead.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAv6vW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the code to show failed use cases (and maybe shorten those names if you do that?).

Comment: @jcalz ha, and there i was thinking i was being helpful 

Comment: @jcalz yes that's exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, although it might be a few hours from now.  The key here is using [mapped tuples](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to get the `IsCompatible<T>` behavior for each element of the passed-in array.  Please test edge cases though; I'd hate to write up a whole answer and then hear "this is great except it doesn't work for this [important thing](//tsplay.dev/mLLV2m) I didn't realize would be an issue" and need to rewrite it (my answers tend to be, uh, extensive).

Comment: Yeah the more I think of it the less I want to start writing an answer until you've tested out the suggestion enough to make sure that edge cases aren't an issue.  The edge case I highlighted earlier might be solved [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mLLVVm) at the expense of making your `IsCompatible<B>` type even more complicated (it's not straightforward to circumvent subtyping).  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz apologises for my delay in response, we must be in completely different timezones

Comment: @jcalz unfortunately yes those edge cases matter, I should have added more explicit use cases to my example code, sorry. I've gone full circle with this now. The intention of `MyGroup` is to avoid the covariant behaviour of an array, to ensure that only compatible types could be grouped together, before then passing the group to another function to be processed.

Comment: @jcalz This code will be consumed by other devs, so i obviously can't control how it's used, but the cases i'm coming across in relation to arrays where it fails don't even seem like self destructive attempts to circumvent the type safety i'm trying to put in place. These issues apply to both the `add` and `addMultiple` methods. I've added a link to the bottom of my post as i'm unable to add the ts playground link to this comment due to it's length

Comment: You can always use https://tsplay.dev to shorten playground links.

Comment: Well, I really don't know how to proceed here. Array covariance doesn't seem to be the real issue; your `IsCompatible<B>` is enforcing the opposite of type safety. Type safety implies the `execute()` method should be allowed to accept wider inputs and produce narrower outputs than you expect. Presumably you're going to call that `execute()` method sometime, right? See [this](//tsplay.dev/wenqVN) for what I mean. If you do want type safety I'd suggest [this](//tsplay.dev/WG6QJm). Without understanding why you seem to want unsafe contravariant outputs and unsafe covariant inputs, I'm stumped.